# Element multiplicities in container?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl

I have a vector of `strings`:

```
std::vector<std::string> data;
```

I need an algorihtm that returns a `std::map<std::string, int>`, storing each distinct `std::string` in `data` along with its multiplicity (how many times it appears repeated in `data`).

Is this implemented in C++ standard libary? Where?

If it is not, can you propose an efficient algorithm to do this?

Comment: This is equivalent to what [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) does in Python. I am looking for a C++ implementation.

Comment: I was thinking about this. Excited for the answer

Comment: @NathanOliver It is not a duplicate. It's similar, but the data types are different. Also I am OK with loops. I think it is a different question

Comment: Why does the data type in the vector matter?

Comment: @NathanOliver It simplifies things. Compare the accepted answer in that question, with the answer from Vlad here. Also note that the OP over there doesn't want to use loops, which restricts things.

Comment: So you got some bonus information.  the first three lines of the second code block does what Vlad did.

Comment: @NathanOliver True, I missed that. It is a duplicate then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, int> counts(const std::vector<std::string>& v)
{
    std::map<std::string, int> result;
    for (auto const& s : v) {
        ++result[s];
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto m = counts({"a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c" });
    for (auto const& e : m)
    {
        std::cout << e.first << " : " << e.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

```
a : 2
b : 1
c : 3
```

Explanation:

with std::map<>, operator[k] will search for the item in the map matching key k. If it not found, (k,v) is inserted into the map where v is a default-initialised value of V. In either case, whether found or not, a reference to the V corresponding to k is returned.

Answer (score 4):

You can just write

```
std::vector<std::string> data;
std::map<std::string, int> m;

//...

for ( const std::string &s : data ) ++m[s];
```

Comment: so this will create new if not found?

Comment: @FirstStep Yes it will.